# Rejected reason: We are not able to continue because we cannot locate the in-app purchases within your app

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, in-app-purchase

I have a project in flutter. I submitted to the `appstore`. It reject showing the error as:

> We have started the review of your app, but we are not able to continue because we cannot locate the in-app purchases within your app.

Then I removed all the subscriptions code from the project and from the `itunes` too and submitted to the `appstore`. And again it rejected saying same error as:

> We have started the review of your app, but we are not able to continue because we cannot locate the in-app purchases within your app.

Now I have all deleted subscriptions from the project and `itunes` too.
Can anyone help to solve this problem? The solutions in `stackoverflow` couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: make sure to add those details in testing note that you have removed all feature related to in-app purchase.

Comment: @PinkeshGjr Do I have to add infomration about removing in-app purchase  in notes of App Review Information ??

Comment: yes so that they be serious to check those thing and not reject without checking those details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not asking you to remove the IAP. They are asking you to tell them how to reach the interface that offers the user the IAP. They don’t see it and they don’t have time to explore. They need instructions. Leave the IAP in, and give them instructions.

Comment: I have removed IAP from app already and it still rejected saying same issues.

Comment: But you didn’t do what I’m saying to do.